# Facebook /me/home FQL equivalent

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

to get the functionality of I want for my app I need to start using FQL.

For the main stream I was using:-

```
$fb_news_feed = $facebook->api('/me/home');
```

what would be the equivelent in FQL that returns the same JSON. My current FQL is below

```
$fb_feed_params = array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => "SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, likes, created_time, type FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'nf' AND is_hidden = 0 LIMIT 100",
);

$fb_news_feed = $facebook->api($fb_feed_params);
```

how do I get the users name etc? I'm guessing I would have to do some kind of join like you would in mysql??

Answer (score 0):

This query should do it -

`SELECT name, username, pic from user WHERE uid IN (SELECT actor_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'nf' AND is_hidden = 0 LIMIT 100)`

Alternatively you could look at doing a multiquery. More information on multiqueries can be found on the facebook developers site:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/